# Gradle exec task returns non-zero exit value and fails the build but I want to not fail and instead perform another task

Tags: gradle

I have an exec task set up in a pretty default way, something like:

```
task myTask(type:Exec) {

    workingDir '.'

    commandLine './myscript.sh'

    doLast {
        if(execResult == 0) {
           //one thing
        } else {
           //another thing
        }
    }
}
```

But unfortunately it never executes the doLast block when an error is thrown by the script. Instead it skips that and fails the entire build with

> Execution failed for task ':project:myTask'.
>   Process 'command './myscript.sh'' finished with non-zero exit value 1"

That's useless to me. The whole idea of myscript.sh finishing with a non-zero exit value is so I can then execute some code in response to it. What do I need to do to not fail the build but capture the result and perform an action in response? Thanks for the help!

Comment: gradle dsl is a simple groovy script, you can just write a try catch block in your task

Answer (score 74, accepted):

TL;DR - Use ignoreExitValue = true

When I read the documentation for about the fiftieth time, I finally saw that there is a property, ignoreExitValue, which defaults to false. But if you set it to true, you can then perform your own tasks in the doLast block.

```
task myTask(type:Exec) {

    workingDir '.'

    commandLine './myscript.sh'

    ignoreExitValue true

    doLast {
        if(execResult.getExitValue() == 0) {
           //one thing
        } else {
           //another thing
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is execResult a thing? I looked through the docs and couldn't find it.

Comment: I am pretty sure that execResult was a variable I had created, and had assigned  the result of the task to it. But this was almost two years ago now so I don't remember.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Exec has a getExecResult(), but JavaExec doesn't. We're using JavaExec, so we just can't use it. :(

Comment: In case anyone needs it, execResult is one of the properties for the Exec task. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html for more info.

Comment: Why I got error **No such property: execResult for class: org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecAction** `exec{
            def command = "command -v docker"
            ignoreExitValue = true
            executable "bash" args "-l", "-c", command
            if(execResult == 0){
                println "Has Docker"
            }else{
                println "No Docker"
            }
        }`

Comment: Hi Kuanlin, try putting your stuff in a block like this instead of "exec":

  `task someTaskName(type: Exec) {
    // stuff you want to do here 
  }`

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html

Comment: `ignoreExitValue true` is not working for me. Getting ` A problem occurred starting process 'command`

Answer (score 7):

If the `ignoreExitValue` answer is not working, another solution is to surround `commandLine` with a `try { ... } catch (Exception e) { ... }`.